# Barclaycard ePDQ Payment Gateway intergration for Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

Im trying to use the WP plugin to intergare to ePDQ, https://wordpress.org/plugins/catchtheweb-barclay-epdq-payment-gateway/

Unfotunately im getting a "Transaction is unsuccessfull!" in the merchant site - the url the plugin redirecting to is https://example.com/wc-api/RapidDive_WC_Gateway_Barclay/ , first of all im not sure if this is the correct url.

any advice much appriciated

Comment: is example.com the domain your using to mask your true domain, or is that the actual URL that the plugin is sending? If so could you try outputting `home_url()` and seeing what that outputs? The WC api url is built from `class-woocommerce.php::754`-`api_request_url()` which uses the `home_url()` to generate that URI

Comment: domain.com is whats the plugin sending , in the ePDQ admin i have given the same domain , so this is the true domian as well.

Comment: well if domain.com is yours that this server sit on thats cool otherwise your home_url may be off, you could test your home_url `define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com' );`; before that check that route exists and is public using something like postman, ie: try https://example.com/wc-api/RapidDive_WC_Gateway_Barclay/ both post and get and got a 404 [change example.com for your domain]

Comment: i can browse example.com/wc-api/RapidDive_WC_Gateway_Barclay it gives a same msg as return from the payment gateway , ie Transaction is unsuccessfull! . which made me think that i dont have the correct return path